# Ubuntu 22.04 - allow drag'n'drop files from Chrome download toolbar to desktop

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-environments, 22.04, drag-and-drop

How can I allow drag'n'drop files from Chrome download toolbar to desktop area:
[image]

Now I can't do it.

Comment: you used to be able to? The files are in your downloads folder (or wherever you set chrome to download them to), why do you need to drag them to your desktop? just open the downloads folder or switch your chrome settings to put downloads on desktop automatically

Comment: Often I use desktop at area for organize downloaded files (move and group them). Not all downloaded files requre me at now for any action.

Comment: Resolved this problem — need to disable wayland mode, with xorg everythinhg work fine.